# In Adobe InDesign, how to print full duplex (both sides of paper)?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, book

When I print or "Print Booklet" in Adobe InDesign, I don't see any options about printing full duplex (both sides of the paper).  I'm using a Mac with a Brother MFC-J6910DW printer.  Does Adobe InDesign not support full duplex printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplex printing is a function of your printer and it's associated drivers and software. Indesign simply prints pages. It is the printer's job to duplex them if it has that capability.

The Brother MFC-J6910DW specifications do state it will duplex. You simply need to tick the option in the print dialog. THere should be an option for "2-Sided" or "Duplex" in the print dialog box provided you've got the drivers installed.

Comment: I've got the right drivers installed off the brother.com website, but there's no 2-sided or duplex printing option.  The print settings dialog is very simple, very few options.

Comment: In Indesign click Print... then the "Printer..." there should be a Two-sided option there.

Comment: Wow!!  how the heck did I miss this before?!?!  I thought I looked absolutely everywhere for that 2-sided option!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InDesign 9 or 10 when you go to the print button under file - Click print - a screen will come up and at the bottom is a button for printer, click that - on the next screen you will see a box with the option to do two sided printing.